# Selenium Grid - Is there a limit to how many simultaneous incoming test connections can be made to a hub?

Tags: selenium, grid

I have a selenium grid set up with several nodes covering different operating systems and browsers which I use for cross-browser compatibility testing for a site. Those tests are automatically triggered as part of the Jenkins-controlled CI, and currently that grid is for the sole use of that site's testing.

However, does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of incoming test connections for a grid? I want to know if I can reuse this grid for testing another site, so a separate set of tests being triggered by different Jenkins jobs.  Will that cause conflicts if the original set of tests happen to be running at the same time, or will the hub simply redirect the new stream of tests to a suitable, free node, and the two sets of tests would run happily in parallel?

If that is the case (parallel running) is there a known limit to how many different sets of tests would be able to use that same hub (assuming enough nodes were connected to service the requests coming in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or will the hub simply redirect the new stream of tests to a suitable, free node, and the two sets of tests would run happily in parallel?

This.

The hub can run as many tests in parallel as there are nodes connected. If a node has more than one browser available, you can use them all, given the [`-maxSession`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) option is set correctly.

This is also interesting:

> `-browser < params >` If -browser is not set, a node will start with 5 firefox, 1 chrome, and 1 internet explorer instance (assuming it’s on a windows box)

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I will work on adding more nodes if necessary in the future rather than having a completely separate grid for this second site.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added another citation that further explains how many browsers each node supports. Didn't know myself that it would start five instances of firefox.